# Magsafe charger getting really hot

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, magsafe

My MagSafe connector gets really hot to the point that it burns my skin when I touch it. Everything else is fine, my macbook charges fine and does not heat up that much. Is this normal?
[image: This Tip Gets Really Hot]

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122530/my-magsafe-to-magsafe-2-converter-becomes-extremely-hot-why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Mag Safe Adapter that gets warm is normal.  So hot that it burns your skin? **Definitely** not normal.

This could be a couple things:

- Your Power Adapter is failing.  If this is the case, replace it with
  a [**GENUINE** Apple Power adapter](http://amzn.to/1Tr2jdj).
- Magsafe DC I/O Board is bad.  From your comments, you said you have a Mid 2015 15" rMBP.  If that is the case, then you will need something like this [MagSafe DC Jack](http://amzn.to/1poQ0RY)

You may want to look at this post [Magsafe connector Scalding hot when charging](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/274236/Magsafe+connector+Scalding+hot+when+charging)

To replace the board, is fairly easy.  Just view the step by step instructions from the same site, [ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_15%22_Core_2_Duo_Models_A1226_and_A1260)

Comment: Its mid 2015 Macbook Pro 15"